# Wrong Focus Outline around anchor content in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, outline

While everything is working fine in Chrome and Firefox, I am having issues in IE displaying correctly the outline focus around the content of some anchor elements.

[image: Error outline]

As you can see in the picture the focus outline is outside the box, in a collapsed status (it looks like a dotted line) and not around it like in the other browsers.

That part of my HTML:

```
<section class='section'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='row mb-lg'>
      <header class='col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center'>
        <h2 class='heading-with-bullet'>
             Box Tests
        </h2>
      </header>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-sm-4'>
        <a href='/tests/test1'>
          <div class='test-box'>
            <div>

              Test1
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class='col-sm-4'>
        <a href='/tests/test2'>
          <div class='test-box'>
            <div>

              Test2
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class='col-sm-4'>
        <a href='/tests/test3'>
          <div class='test-box'>
            <div>

              Test3
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Any idea about on how I could have the focus outline work as expected?
I've only been able to find suggestions on how to remove the outline altogether, which is not ideal for accessibility reasons.

Comment: a very old IE or the IE11? .. by the way, why you said it's wrong ? maybe in the IE world it's correct like this

Comment: IE11. I said Wrong because usually IE shows the dotted focus outline around the content of the anchor (just like Chrome and Firefox) yet it doesn't in this case.

Comment: While HTML5 does allow block-level elements like `<div>` to be wrapped in `<a>` (HTML4 and XHTML1 did not allow this) it still isn't rendered correctly by some browsers (in this case, IE). You'll want to disable the `outline` in the `:focus` style-rule to compensate.

Comment: Can you post the CSS too?